# SQL Agent Job Not Running all the steps

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent job that is supposed to suppress jobs from running in the event that there is a HOLIDAYCD in another table for the given day.  It is running and it is executing the first exec, but the rest are not running.  Here is the code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT HOLIDAYCD FROM CORE.dbo.BANKORGYEARMONTHDAY WHERE CAST(EFFDATE AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
BEGIN
    --On a holiday disable the following jobs
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = 'CORE imports', @enabled = 0
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '086BAE49-50CE-4B87-A8C2-A9386ABEE9D9', @enabled = 0
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '82499D43-2884-4E16-A514-7B666F5AF095', @enabled = 0
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '2581BD28-FA33-48C6-B9E1-7B91C432A2B0', @enabled = 0
END
ELSE
    --On a normal business day, ensure they are enabled
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = 'CORE imports', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '086BAE49-50CE-4B87-A8C2-A9386ABEE9D9', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '82499D43-2884-4E16-A514-7B666F5AF095', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '2581BD28-FA33-48C6-B9E1-7B91C432A2B0', @enabled = 1
```

So what is happening is that the 'CORE imports' job is disabling, but none of the SSRS jobs are.  Is there a better way to stop reports from running on a holiday?  I only have SQL Server Standard 2014 so data driven reports are not an option.

Comment: You might need to wrap the second set of statements after the `ELSE` in a `BEGIN...END` block.

Comment: @IanPreston That was it.  Thank you.  If you post that as an answer, I'll make sure to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ELSE` statements with a `BEGIN...END` block.

i.e.

```
ELSE
BEGIN
    --On a normal business day, ensure they are enabled
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = 'CORE imports', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '086BAE49-50CE-4B87-A8C2-A9386ABEE9D9', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '82499D43-2884-4E16-A514-7B666F5AF095', @enabled = 1
    exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = '2581BD28-FA33-48C6-B9E1-7B91C432A2B0', @enabled = 1
END
```

Without it, only the first statement will be controlled by the `ELSE`; any subsequent statements will not be part of the `IF...ELSE` flow and will always be executed, i.e. in your case always set to enabled.

Answer (score 0):

What I've usually done is added a run/don't run step as the first step of each job, and then have something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT HOLIDAYCD FROM CORE.dbo.BANKORGYEARMONTHDAY
           WHERE CAST(EFFDATE AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM NonExistentTable')
END
```

And then the "On Failure" option for this step is to "Quit the job reporting success".

Although this does lead to repetition across jobs, it also allows you the opportunity to introduce different conditions for whether each job should actually execute.

Comment: This would work for only a few jobs, however, I didn't put all the SSRS jobs in the question.  I'm trying to come up with a method where in one step I can add all jobs I want to stop from running.  Then I can tell people to add jobs there when they need ones that stop running on holidays.  I just don't understand why only the first exec is running and not the rest.